# Simogeo FileManager does not show the images

Tags: javascript, php, windows, file-manager, uwamp

I have Simogeo FileManager version 2.0.0.
I extracted it in root/tools, changed the config file, set up the permissions, hooked it to tinymce and everything seemed to work. The tinymce opens the popup window with FileManager. I can create a folder, change folder and upload files.

Problem is when I upload file(s) I cannot see them in the FileManager but they are uploaded in the directories I created. The only thing I can see are directories.

I am testing it on Windows 8.1 with uwAmp, PHP 5.3.24 or PHP 5.4.31.

Config file:

```
{
        "_comment": "IMPORTANT : go to the wiki page to know about options configuration https://github.com/simogeo/Filemanager/wiki/Filemanager-configuration-file",
    "options": {
        "culture": "en",
        "lang": "php",
        "theme": "flat-dark",
        "defaultViewMode": "grid",
        "autoload": true,
        "showFullPath": false,
        "showTitleAttr": false,
        "browseOnly": false,
        "showConfirmation": true,
        "showThumbs": true,
        "generateThumbnails": true,
        "searchBox": true,
        "listFiles": true,
        "fileSorting": "default",
        "chars_only_latin": true,
        "dateFormat": "d M Y H:i",
        "serverRoot": true,
        "fileRoot": false,
        "relPath": false,
        "logger": false,
        "capabilities": ["select", "download", "rename", "delete", "replace"],
        "plugins": []
    },
    "security": {
        "allowFolderDownload": false,
        "allowChangeExtensions": false,
        "allowNoExtension": false,
        "uploadPolicy": "DISALLOW_ALL",
        "uploadRestrictions": [
            "jpg",
            "jpeg",
            "gif",
            "png",
            "svg",
            "txt",
            "pdf",
            "odp",
            "ods",
            "odt",
            "rtf",
            "doc",
            "docx",
            "xls",
            "xlsx",
            "ppt",
            "pptx",
            "csv",
            "ogv",
            "mp4",
            "webm",
            "m4v",
            "ogg",
            "mp3",
            "wav",
            "zip",
            "rar"
        ]
    },
    "upload": {
        "multiple": true,
        "number": 5,
        "overwrite": false,
        "imagesOnly": false,
        "fileSizeLimit": 16
    },
    "exclude": {
        "unallowed_files": [
            ".htaccess",
            "web.config"
        ],
        "unallowed_dirs": [
            "_thumbs",
            ".CDN_ACCESS_LOGS",
            "cloudservers"
        ],
        "unallowed_files_REGEXP": "/^\\./",
        "unallowed_dirs_REGEXP": "/^\\./"
    },
    "images": {
        "imagesExt": [
            "jpg",
            "jpeg",
            "gif",
            "png",
            "svg"
        ],
        "resize": {
            "enabled":true,
            "maxWidth": 1280,
            "maxHeight": 1024
        }
    },
    "videos": {
        "showVideoPlayer": true,
        "videosExt": [
            "ogv",
            "mp4",
            "webm",
            "m4v"
        ],
        "videosPlayerWidth": 400,
        "videosPlayerHeight": 222
    },
    "audios": {
        "showAudioPlayer": true,
        "audiosExt": [
            "ogg",
            "mp3",
            "wav"
        ]
    },
    "edit": {
        "enabled": true,
        "lineNumbers": true,
        "lineWrapping": true,
        "codeHighlight": false,
        "theme": "elegant",
        "editExt": [
            "txt",
            "csv"
        ]
    },
    "customScrollbar": {
        "enabled": true,
        "theme": "inset-2-dark",
        "button": true
    },
    "extras": {
        "extra_js": [],
        "extra_js_async": true
    },
    "icons": {
        "path": "images/fileicons/",
        "directory": "_Open.png",
        "default": "default.png"
    },
    "url": "https://github.com/simogeo/Filemanager",
    "version": "2.0.0-dev"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the type in referer.

tinymce was passing ?type=image and filemanager expected ?type=images

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. To fix this, you can define your own callback function as follow : http://pastebin.com/mfeaSSFW. See also : http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x:How-to_implement_a_custom_file_browser and http://michaelbudd.org/tutorials/view/28/Building-custom-file-browser-for-TinyMCE-version-4

Comment: Yes, I used this code: `cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=images";`

Comment: Is there another way how to paste the URL to tinymce from filemanager when I choose the image then copy the url and paste it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `listFiles` option is set to `true` inc config file ?

See the related doc : https://github.com/simogeo/Filemanager/wiki/Filemanager-configuration-file

> listFiles Default value true. Display files in right column (filetree). If set to false, will display only folders. Can take value true or false.

For further help, could you copy-paste an URL or at least your config file!?

Comment: I posted the config file. And the listFiles is set to true.

Comment: Also strange is that when I open the URL that is called by AJAX I get array with the images and folders. But if I check the response from AJAX there is just empty array [].

Comment: That's strange indeed ... I would first give you the advice to download and try the [latest trunk version](https://github.com/simogeo/Filemanager/archive/master.zip). If you still experience the bug, you can have a look on apache errors logs, and [enable FM debug option](https://github.com/simogeo/Filemanager/wiki/Enable-log-debug-in-PHP-connector) to see if paths are corrects. By the way, if you want, you can just copy-paste the content of that thread and open a [new issue](https://github.com/simogeo/Filemanager/issues/new) on github.